# how to copy debugger php array variables in php?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

How do I get the values of an array in the variables section of the vscode debug panel?

When I right click on the variable I need to get the value of I get two options to copy. `Copy Value` and `Copy as Expression`, when trying I get the following respectively

- array(1217)
- $missing_performances_ids